# $\int_1^\infty \sin(e^x(x-2))dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Is the following integral converges or diverges? :

$$\int_1^\infty \sin(e^x(x-2))dx$$

I tried to use the assignment $t=e^x$ and I got:

$$\int_1^\infty \sin(e^x(x-2))dx=\int_e^\infty \frac{\sin(t(\ln\ t-2))}{t}dt$$

I thought of comparing it to $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$ and I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $e^{x}\left(x-2\right)=t.
 $ We get $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(e^{x}\left(x-2\right)\right)dx=\int_{-e}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}\frac{W\left(t/e^{2}\right)}{1+W\left(t/e^{2}\right)}dt
 $$ where $W\left(x\right)
 $ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Now since $$\frac{W\left(t/e^{2}\right)}{1+W\left(t/e^{2}\right)}\sim1
 $$ as $t\rightarrow\infty
 $ we have that $$I\sim\int_{-e}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt=\int_{-e}^{0}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt=\textrm{Si}\left(e\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}
 $$ so the integral converges.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $f(x)$ is an increasing function growing faster than $x$, say $\Omega(x^{1+\alpha})$ with $\alpha>0$, from some point on, then
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin(f(x))\,dx $$
is a convergent integral (in the improper Riemann sense) by applying the substitution $x=f^{-1}(t)$ and exploiting [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) - $\sin(t)$ is a function with mean zero.

Comment: By $x=f^{-1}(t)$ you mean the inverse function? because in this integral it's quite hard, I think, to find the inverse function, without using the Lambert function.

Comment: @TrueTopologist: you do not need to find an explicit inverse, that is the point. It is enough to have suitable grow conditions for $f$ to deduce how fast (or, better, how *slow*) $f^{-1}$ goes to $+\infty$, and that settles the question through Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Oh now I understand, thank you very much. This idea can help me with many integrals like so in the future.